# Get WebdriverIO multi-remote to work with Cucumber BDD

Tags: ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am able to start multiple browser sessions in a single test using WebDriverIO's [multiremote](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html) with mocha.

Next I'm trying to get WebDriverIO multiremote work with Cucumber BDD. My [feature definition](https://gist.github.com/webmagit/f5fc18f7b902c8b249abca5d975ef000) is simply to open a browser session and navigate to a url.

Here's my simple [WDIO](https://gist.github.com/webmagit/7d2268170ba8fef59ad8f3cee13e8389#file-wdio-conf-js)

Problem - the browser opens up but navigation does not occur. I have tried to enable the debugger and observe node-inspector but hasn't helped. What am I missing? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to conduct multi-user scenario based testing through BDD. Although I haven't been able to resolve this directly via WebDriverIO I found Chimp (which uses WebDriverIO underneath) has its own flavour of session based automation.

[Chimp's multi-browser testing](https://chimp.readme.io/docs/multi-browser-testing) does exactly what I wanted. Problem solved!

I'm able to write scenarios such as this without explicitly switching the user context.

`Scenario: Able to browse independently
    Given Alice goes to "/features"
    And Bob go to "/bugs"
    Then Alice sees "10" features
    And Bob sees "1" bugs`